# Problemas com Jquery load e append ao carregar outra pagina php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Se possível alguém me ajudar,estou com o seguinte problema.
Ao clicar no menu que se encontra o id de referencia para meu jquery ele carrega
a página apenas com vários cliques no menu e quando aparece eu clico novamente a página some.

Utilizei dois códigos diferentes mas me resultam no mesmo problema.

segue abaixo os códigos.

Script Jquery

```
    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#link1').click(function(event){
         $( "#cliente1" ).load( "c_cliente.php" );

      $.ajax({
          url: 'c_cliente.php',
          cache: false,
          success: function(retorno){
          $('#cliente1').append(retorno);
          }
       });
    });


      /*
         $('#link1').click(function(event){
             $( "#cliente1" ).load( "c_cliente.php" );
        });
        $('#link2').click(function(){
             $( "#cliente1" ).load( "f_funcionario.php" );
        });
      */
   });
</script>
```

Menu

```
<body>

   <div class="overflow_em_container">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="nav-side-menu btn-branco">
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="side-menu" >
        <ul class="nav  navbar-nav ">
         <li id="link1" ><a href="" >Premium</a></li>
         <li id="link2"><a href="">Premium</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Ajuda</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Baixar</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Increver-se</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Entar</a></li>
       </ul>             
     </div>  
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

  <div id="cliente1"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$('#cliente1').html(retorno);` faça essa alteração

Comment: ola, esta a mesma coisa, eu clico aparece uma vez e depois some ai depois dou vários clicks e aparece e quando clico de novo desaparece.

Comment: agora que eu vi! você ta chamando duas funções de ajax no mesmo click???? acho que só precisa disso. `$('#link1').click(function(event){
         $( "#cliente1" ).load( "c_cliente.php" );});`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, era somente o '#' que esqueci de colocar no href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem um elemento `<a>` dentro do seu `<li>`, que está sendo executado quando você clica no parent.

Sugiro a seguinte abordagem:

- Passe a interceptar o click no *`anchor`* (`<a>`), e não no *`list item`* (`<li>`), passando o `id` para o elemento `<a>`;
- Coloque um `href` *dummy* (que não leva a lugar nenhum). O padrão é colocar um hash `#`, e não deixar em branco (embora `''` seja um `href` sintativamente válido, de acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5637990/3889043));
- Cancele o evento que vem do clique. Assim, você trata o *callback* do clique da maneira que quiser e cancela o evento padrão do navegador. Este cancelamento pode ser feito com um `return false;` ou chamar o método `.preventDefault()` no objeto `event`.
- Escolha uma dos métodos jQuery (`ajax` ou `load`). Usei aqui o `load`.

Algo assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#link1').click(function(event){

       $( "#cliente1" ).load( "c_cliente.php" );

       event.preventDefault();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

   <div class="overflow_em_container">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="nav-side-menu btn-branco">
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="side-menu" >
        <ul class="nav  navbar-nav ">
         <li><a href="#" id="link1" >Premium</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="link2" >Premium</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Ajuda</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Baixar</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Increver-se</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Entar</a></li>
       </ul>             
     </div>  
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

  <div id="cliente1"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Cara realmente esqueci do '#'...estava codificando muito rápido é esqueci desse detalhe.Funcionou  das duas maneiras perfeitamente,faltou somente o "#'.Muito obrigado pela ajuda.